# Change button text when paid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am trying to make button dynamic that when user click on "Pay me" button and proceed payment successfully  then button text should be changed into "Paid".

Pleas tell me how can I do this?

My button :

```
<button id="payme">Pay me</button>
```

Comment: Please tell me that you’re not working with online payments.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know payment is successful?. Are you using ajax? If you are using jQuery ajax, you can call the changeText function inside ajax success block.This snippet is just for demo and you can change accordingly

```
function changeText(){
var x =document.getElementById('payme');
x.innerHTML="Paid";
}

setTimeout(function(){
$.ajax({
 url:"https://httpbin.org/get", // Relevant url to validate the sucessfull payment
    success:function(response){
    changeText();
    },
    error:function(response){
   }
})
},2000);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/040nfb85/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would have something like this:

```
$('#payme').on('click', function () {
    $(this).html = "paid";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the text of button after click event use jquery `text()` function :

```
$('#payme').click(function () {
    $(this).text("Paid");
});
```

For the payment process you have to explain more.

Hope this helps.